# The ui-router for angular seems to be cacheing the resolve. When I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

**The Background:**

I am using ui-router for my Angular page routing needs.  It's working great so far, however I'm running into an issue.  When I load a state and I resolve my user object.  I use restangular to make the call to the database and it returns a promise.  Everything works great.  If I then log out, and log in as another user.  Then navigate back to that same page it shows the previous user object.

**Things that I've discovered:**

- The rest api call is being made every time when the state loads, and
  it is the correct information.
- If I place a break point inside my controller the user object that the resolve passes is the cached
  information.

**Theories:**

- The rest API end point is /users/me/, which is the same end point for
  every user.  We just deliver different information based off of the
  JWT token we pass. Somewhere must things since it's the same call
  don't bother delivering the goods it already got.

**Things I've tried:**

- I've confirmed that the API call isn't cached, and it is delivering
  the correct information to angular
- I've tried grabbing the
  $cacheFactory of $http and .removeAll.

**Sample code:**

```
angular.module('services.user', [ ])
  .factory('User', function(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.service('users');
  });

angular.module('settings.profile', [
  'ui.router',
  'services.user'
])

.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('settings.profile',{
      url: '/profile',
      templateUrl: 'app/settings/profile/settings.profile.html',
      controller: 'SettingsProfileCtrl',
      authenticate: true,
      resolve: {
        user: function(User) {
          var user = User.one('me').get()
          return user;
        }
      }
    });
})

.controller('SettingsProfileCtrl',
  function($scope, $location, user, $http, apiUrl){

  $scope.user = user;
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this? I had to put some of my resource fetching into my controllers because of this garbage.

Comment: same questions as @Rell above, this issue is causing me problems. In my case there isn't even an API call - the correct data (cached elsewhere in the application) is being returned via a promise but ui-router is delivering the wrong resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REST API parameter does not change i.e. it stays the same `/users/me/` in all the requests. While the browser may not cache - which is why you see different correct information the cache.

You can try configuring Restangular to validate the theory by doing as below:-

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
```

However I advise you to use URLs and REST API in the spirit of REST style i.e. use something like...

```
/users/me/username
```

where `username` changes based on the user OR if you have some constraints do the following

```
/users/me/?t=timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however in my case the data requested in the resolve property wasn't coming from an API so HTTP caching definitely wasn't the problem.

I added `{reload: true}` for the `options` property in the troublesome `$state.go` call and this seems to have forced ui-router to refresh the resolve property. I no longer get the previous user's roles and permissions, which is nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cache: false` to the state configuration object. But I also recommend adding a different parameter to the requests like `userId` for example.